# Adding awesomefont symbol before text in component button Vue.js

Tags: button, vue.js, icons, components, font-awesome

I want to add a fontawesome phone symbol to my button but for some reason it doesn't seem to work before my span it just shows up with a square.

I'm sure I've set it up correctly, I tested it outside the buttons and it shows up there (see screenshot). We're using scss structure for the css.

```
<template>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <main>
            <div class="elements-wrapper">
                <h2 class="headline">{{ headline }}</h2>
                <h3 class="subtitle">{{ subtitle }}</h3>
                <slotButton class="button-one">
                    <a href="#"><span>Button 1</span></a>
                </slotButton>
                <slotButton class="button-two">
                    <a href="#"><span>Button 2</span></a>
                </slotButton>
                <br>
                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import slotButton from '@/components/SlotButton';

    export default {
        name: 'thank-you',
        components: {
            slotButton,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                headline: 'Headline',
                subtitle: 'Subtitle',
            };
        },
    };
</script>

<style lang='scss'>


/* - Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) - */

.page-wrapper{
    background: linear-gradient(164.1deg, #FF7840 0%, #FF1979 100%);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
    "headerBarThankYou"
    "main";
    grid-template-rows: 10vh auto;

    main{
        .elements-wrapper{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-areas:
            "headline"
            "subtitle"
            "buttonOne"
            "buttonTwo"
            padding: 1rem;
            grid-gap: 0.5rem;
            justify-items: start;

            button{
                a{
                    position: relative;
                    padding-left: 1rem;
                    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
                    text-align: left;
                    background-color: $white;
                    max-width: 20rem;
                    width: 450px;
                    span{
                        font-size: 18px;
                        bottom-margin: 100px;
                        background: linear-gradient(164.1deg, #FF7840 0%, #FF1979 100%);
                        -webkit-background-clip: text;
                        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
                        min-width: 12.5rem;
                        &:before{
                            content: '\f095';
                            font-family: "FontAwesome";
                        }
                    }
                }
                .button-one{
                  grid-area: buttonOne;
                }
                .button-two{
                  grid-area: buttonTwo;
                }
            }

            .headline{
                color: $white;
                @include font-size(26);
                text-align: left;
                grid-area: headline;
            }
            .subtitle{
                color: $white;
                @include font-size(22);
                grid-area: subtitle;
            }
        }
    }
}

    .header-bar-wrapper{
        justify-self: start;
        .company-logo{
            width: 119px;
            margin: 0.5rem auto;
        }
    }
</style>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried to google a solution, it seems that webawesome 4 is slightly different to version 5 and they have some css property setups which are needed like the content and font family, but looking around it seems rather inconsistent to what is needed.

Comment: Are you using Font Awesome 4 or 5 for this?

Comment: Version 5 - https://fontawesome.com/icons/phone?style=solid

Comment: Are you using `npm` to install `font-awesome`?

Comment: No but I downloaded it and added it to my cli, it refers to it correctly. The image above shows that it is working, but just not inside my button component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. My parent component had some styling in it which made it invisible. Thanks anyway